# How to add Session value to DropDownList using SqlDataSource in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-cookies

I have a DropDownList, it is connected with SqlDataSource, I am passing two values in that DropDownList

1.ReportName = it is default value `TotalSales`

2.UserID = it is session Value Session["UserID"]

Here is my code

**Aspx.code**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HQWebMatajer13 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [UserFileName] FROM [ReportSave] WHERE (([ReportName] = @ReportName) AND ([UserID] = @UserID))">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="TotalSales" Name="ReportName" Type="String" />
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="UserID" SessionField="UserID" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here is the [image]

I already pass the value in session from my previous page called **UserReports.aspx**

That page code:

```
protected void linkTotalSales_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["UserID"] = Session["UserID"].ToString();
    Response.Redirect("ReportTotalSalesPivot.aspx");
}
```

When I click the link of `TotalSales` from **UserReports.aspx** page.
It shows the following error

> `DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'UserID'.`

Answer (score 0):

It's showing error because in your datasource you are not selecting UserId and ReportName. You are just Using them as a Condition in your `WHERE` clause.

And I'm not getting that why you're doing like

```
 Session["UserId"] = Session["UserId"].ToString();
```

Because you session is already having a string variable in it. And another thing to note is Session will be dynamic throughout your Web Application.

Comment: If Possible then make your question moore ellaborative so that i can find cause of error. I think you are making mistake in Query only.

Comment: As you said the session values will be passed throughout the application. That is correct I accept that one. But this is not that error occur in my case. I found the solution. I did a mistake in my Aspx code for drop down